# Proftpd server not working on RHEL 7 but smoothly working on RHEL 5.6

Tags: linux, proftpd

all the configurations are same. Just trying to move from A to B. But on B server, I am getting the following error while trying to / testing to login:

[FTP client login error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcEC9.png)

Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Kallol

Comment: What does the [ProFTPD debug logging, debug level 10](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Debugging.html) show?  What does an [`SQLLogFile`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sql.html#SQLLogFile) show?

Answer (score 0):

Your id or password is incorrect as the error message clearly reports.

Comment: Though It looks like that. These ftp servers is running with mysql extension. Both the server have same database and database config. But RHEL 5.5 is working fine, but not on RHEL 7.